# poker tables in apple game center

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a card game for game center. And I'm having troubles with multiplayer: the goal is create 2 types of it - first, public poker table, when user chosen it, he can see all of incomplete poker tables, i.e.
table #1 1 of 3 slots free
table #10 2 of 3 slots free
etc
and he may choose to join some of it
And the second type - private poker table, within creating it, author sets the password which has to be set from other users who wants to join it.
But I can't found any ways to do it by GameKit - it provides only "random" mechanism to join card game, so user is unable to choose table to play(moreover, user cannot see the list of available poker tables), and nobody can pre-set password to protect his game. Does exist some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately game-center multiplayer matches don't work this way. There's no concept of a lobby. A game-center match consist of a session. Your best bet would be to use a 3rd party service, or to roll your own server.